# Delete specific Values of an Array: Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have an array of the shape `(1179648, 909)`.
The problem is that some rows are filled with `0`'s only. I am checking for this as follows:

```
for i in range(spectra1Only.shape[0]):
    for j in range(spectra1Only.shape[1]):
        if spectra1Only[i,j] == 0:
```

I now want to remove the whole row of `[i]` if there is any `0` appearing to get a smaller amount of only the data needed.

My question is: what would be the best method to do so? `Remove`? `Del`? `numpy.delete`? Or any other method?

Comment: **The problem is that some rows are filled with 0's only** and **remove the whole row of [i] if there is any 0 appearing** are contradictory. do you want to remove a row when even a **single value** is `0` or when **all values** are `0`?

Comment: shouldnt make a difference as if there is one 0 the whole row will be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing with `np.any` along `axis=1`:

```
spectra1Only = spectra1Only[~(spectra1Only == 0).any(1)]
```

Here's a demonstration:

```
A = np.random.randint(0, 9, (5, 5))

print(A)

[[5 0 3 3 7]
 [3 5 2 4 7]
 [6 8 8 1 6]
 [7 7 8 1 5]
 [8 4 3 0 3]]

print(A[~(A == 0).any(1)])

[[3 5 2 4 7]
 [6 8 8 1 6]
 [7 7 8 1 5]]
```

Comment: wow thank you so much thats so much easier and totally solves what i needed!

sorry but im a beginner and teaching things somehow by myself